# OpenGL does not render to screen by calling glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0)

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Normally this code renders the image of the texture to screen. But if I now add the command glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0) to the code, it will not render anything. It renders the screens just in the color of glClearColor. I am working with QT so using QOpenGLWidget.

```
glViewport(0, 0, _width, _height);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

_program.bind();
glBindVertexArray(_vao);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(_program.programId(), "u_texture"), 1);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Want can go possibly wrong?

EDIT:

/* final.fsh */

```
# version 330 core

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
in vec4 qt_TexCoord0;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main(void)
{
    fragColor = texture(u_texture, qt_TexCoord0.xy);
}
```

/* final.vsh */

```
# version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_position;

out vec4 qt_TexCoord0;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position =  vec4(a_position, 1.0);

    const mat4 B = mat4(0.5,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                            0.0,  0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
                            0.0,  0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
                            0.5,  0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

    qt_TexCoord0 = B * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

/* Loads VAO to GPU */

```
GLfloat max_ = 1.0;
GLfloat min_ = -1.0;
GLfloat vert[] = {
    max_,  max_, 0,
    max_, min_, 0,
    min_, max_, 0,

    max_,  min_, 0,
    min_, min_, 0,
    min_,  max_, 0,
};

glGenVertexArrays(1, &_vao);
glBindVertexArray(_vao);

GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vert), vert, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat)*3, (GLvoid*)0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: Calling `glBindFramebuffer` with a target of `0` will [break any existing binding to `GL_FRAMEBUFFER`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindFramebuffer.xhtml).  Given that that's the case it's not obvious why you're calling it.  What's the intention?

Comment: The idea is to have in future some additional render calls to a frame buffer. And then pass the result to that code to render the result on screen.

Comment: `glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK)` should do the trick I guess

Comment: Mhh, don't know how this could help. Where should this stand? I don't bind any frame buffer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated by G.M., and according to [the docs](http://docs.gl/gl4/glBindFramebuffer), `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)` "breaks the existing binding of a framebuffer object to the target". You need this call after having used your framebuffers to do some offscreen rendering. When you want to finally render to the screen, you have to render the the *back buffer*, by calling `glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK)`.

So your render loop might look like

```
// Do some rendering stuff in n offscreen textures
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, the_buffer);
glDrawBuffers(n, buffers);
// Rendering calls

// Finally use the results for the final rendering 
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
// Rendering calls
```

EDIT:
It appears you are using `QOpenGLWidget` as your `OpenGL` provider / windowing system. The `Qt` guys are using framebuffers to render their UI, and the content of the result of your `QOpenGLWidget` is drawn inside an FBO.

So, what it means (at least in my experience, there might be a better way to tackle this problem), is that you cannot render in the backbuffer anymore, you have to render in `Qt`s `framebuffer`.

One way to do this (again, it might not be the best way at all, but it has worked for me), is to save the bound framebuffer at the begining of your rendering, and do your final rendering in this buffer. Which leads to

```
// First of all, save the already bound framebuffer
GLint qt_buffer;
glGetIntegerv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING, &qt_buffer);

// Do some rendering stuff in n offscreen textures
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, your_buffer);
glDrawBuffers(n, buffers);
// Rendering calls

// Finally use the results for the final rendering 
if (glIsFramebuffer(qt_buffer))
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
}
else
{
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, qt_buffer);
    glDrawBuffers(1, buffers);
}
// Rendering calls
```

Comment: Ok, for testing that, I doubled my code. And changed glBindFramebuffer to a successfully created FBO. with : GLuint attachement[2] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
    glDrawBuffers(2, attachement);  And the rest like you showed, by binding 0 again to Framebuffer with glDrawBuffer. But nothing changed

Comment: Wait, are you using Qt's `QOpenGLWidget`  ?

Comment: Yes, is there a difference?

Comment: Ohh yeah. That worked ^^ I actually used GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING to get the FBO. But i called it after initializing OpenGL, and there it told me it was 0 ^^. But yeah I had to move it to the paintGL(). Thank you

Comment: Glad it does the job :) May I suggest you to edit your question to include the fact that you are using `QOpenGLWidget` ? It might help other people :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and finally I find the cause is `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);`
QOpenGLWidget's default framebuffer may not be 0, so you need to get it by calling `QOpenGLContext::defaultFramebufferObject()`

so change like this:

```
glViewport(0, 0, _width, _height);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebufferObject()); //<-- change here

glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

_program.bind();
glBindVertexArray(_vao);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(_program.programId(), "u_texture"), 1);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```